# Pytorch - RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Sequential: Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "0.weight", "0.bias",

Tags: pytorch

I have created a Pytorch object from  the class `Sequential` (see [official page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html)).
As they suggest, I am saving it using the command `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)`.

It seems that everything has worked fine, since when I use `torch.load(PATH)` in another file I get
an ordered Dict like

```
'0.weight': tensor([[ 0.1202, ...]]) ,
'0.bias':  tensor([ 0.1422, ...]) ,
...
```

with all the shapes of the tensors being correct. However, when doing

```
model = Sequential()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Sequential:
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "0.weight", "0.bias", "2.weight", "2.bias", "4.weight", "4.bias".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to load, the model you are trying to load into (`model`) is an empty `Sequential` object with no layers. On the other hand, looking at the error message, the state dictionary of the model you are trying to load from indicates that it has at least five layers, with the first, third, and fifth layers containing a weight and bias parameter. This is a mismatch since the corresponding layers and parameters do not exist in `model`.

To fix this, `model` should have the same architecture as the saved model you are trying to load. Since you say you saved the original model yourself, use an identical initialization step when creating `model`.